# Laravel 5.5 Storing image from base64 string

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.5 project, I have successfully saved the info into product table in MySQL. The info include a base64 string which is an image basically. However, I'm facing an issue while stroing the image in public folder of the laravel project. Below is my code for the ProductController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $data = $request->validate([
        'product_name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
        'rating' => 'required'
    ]);

    $uploaded_image = $request->input('uploaded_image');
    $data['uploaded_image'] = $uploaded_image['value']; // base64 string
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
    $product->update($data);
    // the data stored into the database with no issue

    $image_base64 = base64_decode($uploaded_image['value']);
    $path = public_path();
    $success = file_put_contents($path, $image_base64.".png");

    return response()->json($data);
}
```

I see the following error below:

```
message:"file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-api\public): failed to open stream: Permission denied"
```

By seeing different sources, I did the following, but nothing changed.

1. php artisan clear-compiled
2. Icacls public /grant Everyone:F
3. composer dump-autoload

Any idea?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168307/discussion-on-question-by-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara-laravel-5-5-storing-image).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per our discussion you need to give permissions like:

```
icacls "public" /grant USER:(OI)(CI)F /T
```

Where `USER` is your pc's user

Also, if you want to save base64 image in storage path then use the following code:

```
//Function to save a base64 image in laravel 5.4
public function createImageFromBase64(Request $request){

      $file_data = $request->input('uploaded_image');
      //generating unique file name;
      $file_name = 'image_'.time().'.png';
      //@list($type, $file_data) = explode(';', $file_data);
      //@list(, $file_data)      = explode(',', $file_data);
      if($file_data!=""){
        // storing image in storage/app/public Folder
        \Storage::disk('public')->put($file_name,base64_decode($file_data));     
      }
}
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving permission as `icacls "public" /grant USER:(OI)(CI)F /T` we can store the files/ images as follows

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('Items_attachments/'.$img_name, base64_decode($data));
```

`Items_attachments` - is the sub folder inside the public

`$img_name` - the name for base64 string

`$data` - is the decoding object